# XeLaTeX: Polyglossia and Hebrew Calendar (Suspected Type1 Font error)

Tags: fonts, xetex, hebrew

I tried adding Hebrew date to my document using `\today` as in the code below.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}

\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=hebrew]{hebrew}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

However, this code doesn't compile with XeLateX. Instead, the process terminates with the following error.

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: This font using the "seac" command for accented characters
```

From searching online it seems to be related to type1 fonts, as `xdvipdfmx` can't work with them. However, the Hebrew fonts I know are type1 (from Culmus).

Is there any way to circumvent this problem, and display the Hebrew date properly?

Comment: I found some TrueType fonts on my machine and they show no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to use type1 fonts with xelatex (at least not for text).

There is here http://culmus.sourceforge.net/taamim/ a `Taamey David CLM` which is based on David CLM and works fine with xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Taamey David CLM}

\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=hebrew]{hebrew}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

[image]